# Error in 'group by' stating its a character for looping through summarise R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

still getting to grips with R, and as a newbie, as I have been doing most of my coding manual, ie copy and paste the same block of code 20 times. Here, I was trying to learn about looping and summarising. When I do the summarise with one individual dataset, it works fine, but now I try and loop it, it states its a character, so I added in 'as.numeric' to no prevail. Any advice would be helpful.

Error:

Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

```
#educationYears

fiv0_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2005')
six0_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2006')
sev0_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2007')
eig0_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2008')
nin0_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2009')
ten_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2010')
one_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2011')
two_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2012')
thr_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2013')
for_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2014')
fiv_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2015')
six_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2016')
sev_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2017')
eig_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2018')
nin_education <- subset(sf_education, Year  == '2019')

names <- c('fiv0', 'six0', 'sev0', 'eig0', 'nin0', 'ten', 'one', 'two', 'thr', 'for', 'fiv', 'six', 'sev', 'eig', 'nin')

test <- vector("list", length(names))

for (i in 1:length(names)) {
test[i] <- paste(names[i], '_education', sep = "", collapse = NULL) %>% 
    group_by(as.numeric(as.character(Kod))) %>% 
    summarise(Count=sum(as.numeric(as.character(Count))))
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `paste` retunrs a character object, it has nothing to do with the class of `Kod`. Step 1) `tmp <- paste(...)`. Step 2) `test[[i]] <- get(tmp) %>% etc`. See if it works. If not please follow the next comment.

Comment: It's a good start to give some data (an example of your dataset sf_education) and give an example of your desired output.

Comment: Can you post sample data? `rbind` 2 or 3 of the subsetted dataframes into one `df` and please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: @martinGal / RuiBarradas - apologies, I am still new to Stack Overflow, your feedback is taken into account if there is a next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using built-in data set `iris` as an example. I believe it's easy to adapt to the problem in the question.

**1.** A solution with a `for` loop, like in the question.

```
library(dplyr)

names <- c('fiv0', 'six0', 'sev0')

test <- vector("list", length(names))
for (i in 1:length(names)) {
  tmp <- paste0(names[i], '_education')
  test[[i]] <- get(tmp, envir = .GlobalEnv) %>%
    mutate(Count = as.numeric(as.character(Count))) %>%
    group_by(Kod) %>% 
    summarise(Count = sum(Count))
}

test
#[[1]]
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#    Kod Count
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1   1.6
#2     2   3.7
#3     3   2.4
#4     4   4.6
#
#[[2]]
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#    Kod Count
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1  24.5
#2     2  27.2
#3     3  19.1
#4     4  30.5
#
#[[3]]
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#    Kod Count
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1  15.9
#2     2  18.9
#3     3  15.5
#4     4  16
```

**2.** Here is another way, with `purrr::map`.
This code uses the data set already split in several with `subset`.

```
paste0(names, '_education') %>%
  mget(envir = .GlobalEnv) %>%
  purrr::map(
    function(X){
      X %>%
        mutate(Count = as.numeric(as.character(Count))) %>%
        group_by(Kod) %>% 
        summarise(Count = sum(Count))
    }
  )
```

**3.** Another `purrr:map` way, but this time from the original data set, with no need to `subset` multiple times first.

Note that the splitting column here is `Species`, in the question it's `Year`.

```
df1 %>%
  group_split(Species) %>%
  purrr::map(
    function(X){
      X %>%
        mutate(Count = as.numeric(as.character(Count))) %>%
        group_by(Kod) %>% 
        summarise(Count = sum(Count))
    }
  )
```

## Data creation code.

```
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- iris[4:5]
names(df1)[1] <- "Count"
df1$Kod <- sample(4, 150, TRUE)
fiv0_education <- subset(df1, Species  == 'setosa')
six0_education <- subset(df1, Species  == 'virginica')
sev0_education <- subset(df1, Species  == 'versicolor')
```